# No tests were executed (Play Framework)

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, sbt

I'm having an issue with running my unit tests in a `Play Framework` application.
I'm currently using `v 2.6.11` of Play and `sbt 0.13.17`. Tests have worked in the past, but It seems that now `sbt` cannot execute them.

If I simply run `sbt test` I get `No tests were executed.`. If I start `sbt` with `sbt --debug` I get a more verbose log with the following:

`[debug] [naha]  .
[debug] [naha] All member reference dependencies will be considered within this context.
[debug] [naha] New invalidations:
[debug] [naha]  Set()
[debug] [naha] Initial set of included nodes: Set()
[debug] [naha] Previously invalidated, but (transitively) depend on new invalidations:
[debug] [naha]  Set()
[debug] [naha] All newly invalidated sources after taking into account (previously) recompiled sources:Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.Suite,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@1883984e), (junit.framework.TestCase,false,com.novocode.junit.JUnit3Fingerprint@420f0739))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.WrapWith,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$2@453e6a3d), (org.junit.runner.RunWith,false,com.novocode.junit.RunWithFingerprint@7fb29b6c), (org.junit.Test,false,com.novocode.junit.JUnitFingerprint@7760adb))
[debug] javaOptions: List()
[debug] Forking tests - parallelism = false
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 38 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[debug] Summary for JUnit not available.
[debug] Forcing garbage collection...`

This is my `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  filters,
  guice,
  // Bunch of Dependencies
)

dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "io.ebean" % "ebean" % "11.14.3" withSources()
)

// Remove dependencies because of Multiple Bindings to SLF4J
excludeDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12"
excludeDependencies += "org.log4j" % "log4j"

// Don't know why But activator stage started to complain while Compiling
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974766/play2-play-stage-command-fails-with-not-found-type-setupcontext
sources in doc in Compile := List()
```

I've tried adding `crossPaths := false` as per [this thread in Github](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/issues/35)

Since I saw that message on `Missing Implementations` I've added this to my `build.sbt` (through various google searches):

`"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test,
"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test,
"org.exparity" % "hamcrest-date" % "2.0.0" % Test`

But without luck. I've been at it all morning in various Stackoverflow threads and github issues [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972284/scalatest-on-sbt-not-running-any-tests), [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/iv4O9yNH0u0) or [this](https://github.com/jbrisbin/akka-http-docker/issues/3)

If any one has some ideas on how I can debug this situation.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this worked:

Open sbt console: `sbt`

Run the tests: `testOnly *` or `test *`

So adding the `*` fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. But unfortunately it did not work.
`test *` is unrecognized by `sbt`
`testOnly *` is executed, but no tests are run

Comment: have you tried `testOnly *Test*` or something else that matches a testname?

Comment: I tried `testOnly *`, `testOnly com.package.*` `testOnly com.*` and `testOnly com.package.ClassWithJunitTest*`

Answer (score 2):

If you are running JUnit tests add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

It might be the case that JUnit tests are indeed running, but the log events are at `DEBUG` level so you cannot see them. According to [docs](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/blob/master/README.md) `-v` option logs them at `INFO` level:

> Log "test run started" / "test started" / "test run finished" events
>   on log level "info" instead of "debug".

On my machine setting `-v` option gives me the following output in sbt:

```
[info] Test run started
[info] Test com.gu.identitycommon.clickthrough.TokenServiceTest.shouldFlagInvalidPasswordResetTokens started
[info] Test com.gu.identitycommon.clickthrough.TokenServiceTest.shouldEndcodeAndDecodeActivationToken started
[info] Test com.gu.identitycommon.clickthrough.TokenServiceTest.shouldDecoedToNullUserGroupIfNoneProvidedInActivationToken started
[info] Test com.gu.identitycommon.clickthrough.TokenServiceTest.shouldRecognizeValidPasswordResetTokens started
[info] Test run finished: 0 failed, 0 ignored, 4 total, 0.276s
[info] Test run started
```

while without `-v` test option there is no output.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in, without much explanation things started working again (I did clean, cleanFiles, compile, stage) and in a mix of that, things started working (didn't need to try your solution). But I'm upvoting it because I might need it in the future.